# SQL Checking if a user relationship exist

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have a user relationship table set up that looks like this.

### user_relationship

- relationship_id
- requesting_user_id
- requested_user_id
- relationship_type
- relationship_status

Now say I want to check a relationship to see if it exist between two users who lets say for this example are IDs 1 & 2. I could do a:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_relationship 
 WHERE (requesting_user_id='1' AND  requested_user_id='2') 
    || (requesting_user_id='2' AND  requested_user_id='1')
```

But I am wondering if their is a better faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

ORs are notoriously bad performers.  You could try a UNION instead:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM USER_RELATIONSHIP a
 WHERE a.requesting_user_id = '1' 
   AND a.requested_user_id = '2'
UNION
SELECT b.* 
  FROM USER_RELATIONSHIP b
 WHERE b.requesting_user_id = '2' 
   AND b.requested_user_id = '1'
```

UNION will remove duplicates; `UNION ALL` will not (and is faster for it).

If there are any columns coming back that you don't use -- they shouldn't be in the query.

Indexing should be on:

- requesting_user_id
- requested_user_id

...either separately or a single composite index but you'll have to test to know which works best.

Comment: +1 - And if you do a covering index, make sure your `WHERE` clauses are always in the same order as the indexed columns

Comment: MySQL will only use one index per table lookup, so having individual indexes on both columns would probably not be helpful.

Comment: @TehShrike: Yeah, composite index makes most sense after I wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that a user can not send a request to themselves, this should be equivalent:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_relationship
WHERE requesting_user_id IN(1, 2) AND requested_user_id IN(1, 2);
```

I doubt this would actually be any faster, but it is at least easier to read (in my opinion).

Make sure you have a single index that covers both requesting_user_id and requested_user_id - if you are doing this query often, such an index is definitely a requirement.

Comment: Using `IN` has the possibility of returning records will 1 is in both fields/columns, assuming such data is allowed.  It's a reach, but a concern for false positives.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: definitely - that's why I lead with the qualifier "If you assume that a user can not send a request to themselves".  If that is not the case, then my query is not equivalent.

Comment: You can add the condition `and requesting_user_id != requested_user_id`